# Gmail API Reply to an email keeping the original message in Quotes - Python

Tags: gmail-api

When replying to an email, I want to include the original message in the quotes. But the quoted message is not being displayed properly starting with a gray bar.

Below is my code:

```
    def send_message(self, event):
        
        service = self._get_gmail_service()
        message = EmailMessage()
        original_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(event["original_message"]).decode("utf-8")
        quoted = f"On {event['original_message_date']}, {event['original_message_from']} wrote: \n"

        for line in original_text.splitlines():
            if line.startswith(">"):
                quoted += ">"
            else:
                quoted += "> "
            quoted += line + "\r\n"

        replyText = event["message"] + "\n\n\n" + quoted

        print(replyText)

        message.set_content(replyText)
        message["To"] = event["To"]
        message["Cc"] = event["Cc"]
        message["From"] = event["From"]
        message["Subject"] = event["Subject"]
        message["In-Reply-To"] = event["In-Reply-To"]
        message["References"] = event["References"]

        create_message = {
            'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode(),
            'threadId': event["threadId"]
        }

        send_message = (service.users().messages().send
                        (userId=self.subject, body=create_message).execute())
        print(F'Message Id: {send_message["id"]}')
        return send_message
```

This is how it looks in Gmail
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BneRl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
    def send_message(self, event):
        
        service = self._get_gmail_service()
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message["To"] = event["To"]
        message["Cc"] = event["Cc"]
        message["From"] = event["From"]
        if event["Subject"].upper().startswith("RE:"):
            message["Subject"] = event["Subject"]
        else:
            message["Subject"] = "Re: " + event["Subject"]
        message["In-Reply-To"] = event["In-Reply-To"]
        message["References"] = event["References"]
        original_text = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(event["original_message"]).decode("utf-8")
        event["message"] = event["message"].replace('\n', '<br />')

        body = '<div dir="ltr">' \
               + event["message"] \
               + '</div><br><br><br>' \
               + '<div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr" class="gmail_attr">' \
               + 'On ' + event["original_message_date"] + ' at ' \
               + event["original_message_time"] + ' ' + event["original_message_from"] \
               + ' wrote:<br></div>' \
               + '<blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0.8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex">' \
               + original_text \
               + '</div>' \
               + '</blockquote>'

        msg = MIMEText(body, 'html')
        message.attach(msg)
        # print(message)

        create_message = {
            'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode(),
            'threadId': event["threadId"]
        }

        send_message = (service.users().messages().send
                        (userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
        print(F'Message Id: {send_message["id"]}')
        return send_message
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).